# Eulers method for a non-linear boundary value problem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

As part of an assignment, I have been asked to numerically solve the following 2nd-order differential equation. For those wondering, it is a model of groundwater flow through an aquifer beset on both sides by canals.

$${d^2y(l)\over dl^2} = -{R\over K}y(l)^{-1}$$

$$0 \le l \le L$$
$$y(0) = 3$$
$$y(L) = 2$$

Using Euler's Method. I intend to write a script in MatLab to do this for me. *R* and *K* are constants. Since we are talking about a second order (nonlinear?) DE, I started of with rewriting it as a system of first-order differential equations.

Let $x_1(l) = y(l)$. Let $x_2 = x_1'(l) = y'(l)$ Then $x_2'(l) = y"(l)$. The system then becomes:

- $x_1'(l) = x_2(l)$
- $x_2'(l) =  -{R\over K}x_1(l)^{-1}$

And this is where I get stuck. All the literature I have read explains the method of rewriting a $n^{th}$-order DE into a system of first-order equations, but only for linear initial value problems. So:

- How do I incorporate the boundary condition at *y(L)*?
- What to do about the fact I have no boundary conditions for *y'(l)*? It seems to me that I can never compute the first iteration without knowing a boundary *y'(0)*.

As a quick side-question,

$${d^2y(l)\over dl^2}y(l) = -{R\over K}$$
$${d^2y(l)^2\over dl^2} = -{R\over K}$$

Is just plain wrong, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Euler's method is for initial value problems, not boundary value problems. You can try a couple of things.

**Shooting method**: solve the problem wiyh initial values $y(0)=3$, $y'(0)=a$, where $a$ is a parameter; call $y(x,a)$ the solution. Now you have to solve $y(L,a)=2$. You can do this looking for $a_1,a_2$ such that $y(L,a_1)<3<y(L,a_2)$ and usng the *midpoint* method.

**Finite differences**: Take a large $N$, let $h=L/N$ and $l_k=k\,h$, $0\le k\le N$. Let $y_k$ be an approximation of $y(l_k)$. Approximate the differential equation by the system
$$
\frac{y_{k+1}-2\,y_k+y_{k-1}}{h^2}=-\frac{R}{K}y_k^{-1},\quad1\le k\le N
$$
complemented with $y_0=y(0)=3$, $y_N=y(L)=2$. Solve the system. Since it is a nonlinear system, use Newton-Ralphson.

Answer (score 1):

Using Mr. Aguirre's suggestions, I solved the problem. The 'shooting' method would still require a reasonable guess to the value of $y'(0)$, and even then result in many iterations. Instead of opting for the 'shooting' method, I used Finite Differences instead (After checking with the professor, of course).

Using the central differences scheme, the differential equation can be rewritten as:

$$y_{k-1}-2y_{k}+y_{k+1}+ h^2{R\over K}y_k^{-1} = 0$$

From this, we get a system of equations. Note, that we substitute $y_{k=0}$ for $y(l=0)$, and $y_{k=N+2}$ for $y_L$.

$$f_1 = -2y_1+y_2+h^2{R\over K}y_1^{-1}-y(l=0)=0$$
$$f_2 = y_1-2y_2+y_3+h^2{R\over K}y_2^{-1}=0$$
$$ ...$$
$$f_{N-1} = y_{N-2}-2y_{N-1}+y_{N}+h^2{R\over K}y_{N-1}^{-1}=0$$

$$f_{N} = y_{N-1}-2y_{N}+h^2{R\over K}y_{N}^{-1}-y(l=L)=0$$

This system may be rewritten as a tri-diagonal matrix for the discretisation (call it $A$), a vector $B$ to include the $h^2{R\over K}y_k^{-1}$ term, and a boundary-value vector ($C$). $F$ then becomes the sum of $Ay+B+C$, thus a vector.

For the Newton-Raphson algorithm we also need an initial guess as to what $y$ could be. I chose all elements of $y$ as 2. It works fine for other values, but remember Newton's method can be unstable at times.

$$y_{p+1} = y_p + J(y_p)^{-1}F(y_p)$$ 
Where J is the Jacobian matrix of the original system of equations. It is (see the equations) tri-diagonal.